# Conversion between angle with axis & angle with axial plane

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle

Let's imagine in 3D space I have three angle, $\theta_x$,$\theta_y$,$\theta_z$ respectively with *X-axis*, *Y-axis*, *Z-axis*.

Just like $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ here:

[image]

I also have $\theta_{xy},\theta_{yz},\theta_{zx}$ angle respectively with *plane-XY*, *plane-YZ*, *plane-ZX*.

Just like *r*,$\theta$,$\sigma$ here:
[image]

**What are relation between them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's name a unit vector $v$ with these angles, so 
$$
v = \pmatrix{x \\y\\z}
$$
with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. The assumption on the axis-angles says that 
$$
\cos \theta_x = x\\
\cos \theta_y = y\\
\cos \theta_z = z
$$
What about $\theta_{xy}$? The angle between $v$ and the $xy$-plane is ... well, that depends. Suppose that $z > 0$. Then the angle is somewhere between $0$ and $\pi/2$, right? What if $z < 0$ --- is the angle between $-\pi/2$ and $0$? Or is it again in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$?

I'm going to assume the first case. Let's start with $z > 0$. Then the angle $\theta_z$ from $v$ to the $z$-axis is $\arccos(z)$, and so the angle from $v$ to the $xy$-plane is $\pi/2$ minus this, i.e., $\theta_{xy} = \pi/2 - \theta_z$.

Now let's look at the case $z < 0$. I'm going to assume that this produces an angle $\theta_{xy}$ that's in the interval $[-\pi/2, 0]$. When $\theta_z = \pi/2$, we want $\theta_{xy} = 0$; when $\theta_z = \pi$, we want $\theta_{xy} = -\pi/2$. Because we know they're linearly related, we see that $\theta_{xy} + \theta_z = \pi/2$, hence $\theta_{xy} = \pi/2 - \theta_z$.

Aha! The same formula applies in both cases, so we have
$$
\theta_{xy} =\pi/2 - \theta_z\\
\theta_{xz} =\pi/2 - \theta_y\\
\theta_{yz} =\pi/2 - \theta_x
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot . I was doing it in a lot complex way, which was costing a lot of time. Now it will be super smooth. **I was taking ratio of $\theta_x$ and $\theta_y$ then doing a lot of unnecessary calculation . Thanks again.

Comment: And maybe you need to edit this : $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Comment: Ooops! Fixed!  ~~